# Screenshot algorithm is giving blank areas in Win10 - worked fine in all other Windows versions

Tags: winapi

I used the following method to take a screenshot of all the monitors. It works flawlessly, but I just upgraded to Windows 10 and am seeing a major issue. I am getting blank/transparent areas.

Regular screenshot using `PrtScn`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/octsD.png

Using my algorithm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NivwE.png

### my algorithm details

My algorithm is called from a Firefox, and it takes a screenshot after 5 seconds. At the time of screenshot, Notepad++ was focused.

1. `EnumDisplayDevices`
2. `CreateDC` with `lpszDriver` and `lpszDevice` obtained from step 1
3. `CreateCompatibleDC` on result of step 2
4. `CreateDIBSection` on result of step 2
5. `SelectObject` results of step 2 onto result of step 4
6. `BitBlt`

Here is the WinAPI calls from my code, it is in js-ctypes:

```
ostypes.API('EnumDisplayDevices')(null, iDevNum, lpDisplayDevice.address(), 0);
var hdcScreen = ostypes.API('CreateDC')(collMonInfos[s].otherInfo.lpszDriver, collMonInfos[s].otherInfo.lpszDevice, null, null);
var hdcMemoryDC = ostypes.API('CreateCompatibleDC')(hdcScreen); 
var hbmp = ostypes.API('CreateDIBSection')(hdcScreen, bmi.address(), ostypes.CONST.DIB_RGB_COLORS, pixelBuffer.address(), null, 0);
var rez_SO = ostypes.API('SelectObject')(hdcMemoryDC, hbmp);
var rez_BB = ostypes.API('BitBlt')(hdcMemoryDC, 0, 0, w, h, hdcScreen, 0, 0, ostypes.CONST.SRCCOPY);
// i then draw pixelBuffer to a html5 canvas
```

Has anyone else experienced these blank spaces? Anyone know solution?

Comment: What happens when you do this from a normal app and not inside firefox

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan for the quick reply,  I had passed out it was 5am my time :P Im not sure how to do this from normal app. Can you please tell me how I can try.

Comment: You just call those same function from a C++ program.

Comment: Oh I don't have a C or C++ environment but I'll download VS2013 and update you. :)

Comment: I think it's foolish to do this stuff without access to native tools

Comment: Haha ok Ill go learn it

Comment: Hey @DavidHeffernan I tried it from regular app, and it is also giving me blanks :( here is my cpp - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e7aaa201798d019e92b2

Comment: So this makes it a pure winapi question. You'd be better making a new Q with a full mcve in C++. Although I bet the question has been asked before.

Comment: Thanks @David I created it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006966/the-dependable-screenshot-method-gives-transparent-areas-in-windows-10